# Redux reducer does not force a rerender on my React Component although I mutated the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been struggling with redux lately because it often does not let my React Components rerender. I know that I have to mutate the state in order to let redux know that my state changed. But for some reason, my Redux still doesn't trigger the componentDidUpdate() function on my React Component.
Here is the code for my reducer function:

```
case ADD_OR_UPDATE_EVENT_OF_MATCH: {
            const matches = [...state.matches];
            const foundMatch = matches.find((match) => match.matchId === action.matchId);
            const foundMatchIndex = matches.findIndex((match) => match.matchId === action.matchId);
            if (!foundMatch) return state;


            if (foundMatch.events) {
                const foundEventIndex = foundMatch.events?.findIndex((event) => event.eventId === action.event.eventId);
                if (foundEventIndex === -1) {
                    foundMatch.events?.push(action.event);
                } else {
                    foundMatch.events[foundEventIndex] = action.event;
                }

            } else {
                foundMatch.events = [action.event];
            }

            matches[foundMatchIndex] = foundMatch;
            if (state.currentMatch) {
                if (foundMatch.matchId === state.currentMatch.matchId) {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        currentMatch: foundMatch,
                        matches: matches
                    };
                } else {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        matches: matches
                    };
                }
            }

            return state;
        }
```

Comment: If possible can you share you add complete code on codesandbox[https://codesandbox.io/]? Its not always reducer have problem. Sometime code wise implementation is wrong

Comment: @ShubhamVerma This is a giant project I am working on for my company, therefore I cannot share more code than this. But all I was checking is, if after the reducer my React Component that uses the state, calls the componentDidUpdate() method, which it did not. But other mutation of the same state calls the componentDidUpdate() method. So my suggestion here is that my reducer does something wrong. Maybe because of the use of the spread operator? Maybe Redux does not notice that the state was mutated or something?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma As it seems, when I am debugging the reducer, the hasChanged value from Redux is true, therefore you were right, my mistake seems to be somewhere different. Really weird how my componentDidUpdate does not shoot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this statement is very wrong:

> I know that I have to mutate the state in order to let redux know that my state changed.

The exact opposite is true. **You should *never* actually mutate Redux state!**

Lines like this are mutating, and are therefore breaking your app:

```js
foundMatch.events[foundEventIndex] = action.event;
```

You need to change this logic to all be [immutable updates](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns), instead.

You should also probably look at using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) to write your Redux logic, as it does allow you to write "mutating" logic in reducers that gets turned into safe and correct immutable updates internally.